# CKEditor working on localhost but not on server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ckeditor

Facing issue with ckeditor on server.Everything works fine when running the application locally but hosting it on IIS server, the ckeditor was not visible.

I tried few steps like adding  , but still faced same issue. I suppose the page is unable to find JS file on specified path.

Checking in console I was able to see ckeditor script on my page.

Below is the code :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

  <table style="width: 100%; height: 333px;">
   <tr>
   <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp; Title&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; :&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp; &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" Height="29px" Width="451px" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblNewsId" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp; Description&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; :&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="txtDescp" BasePath="/ckeditor/"   runat="server">
   </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  </table>
```

Comment: If you open your browser's developer tools or a sniffer like Fiddler, do you see 404 errors trying to fetch ckeditor.js?

Comment: how should I check it in chrome??

Comment: Press F12 to get the developer tools. If you look in the console section, you should see errors if other files like JS files fail to load

Comment: yes some files are failing to load...Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Atzmon thank you so much! You helped me discover where the problem was at!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script src is relative to your page location (starts with two dots): `src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"`

This means that if your asp.net page is located in a sub folder, then the ckeditor folder will not be found.

You can use `ResolveClientUrl()` to render the correct src at runtime:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/ckeditor/ckedtor.js")%>"></script>`

Or, if you know the your application location will remain the same locally and remotely (for example http://localhost/myapp and also http://myserver/myapp) you can set the src starting from the root:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/myapp/ckeditor/ckedtor.js"></script>`

Comment: It help resolved the issue.Thank you for your suggestion.I think the script address was wrongly called.